# JSON Schema: required boolean fields don't work correctly

Tags: java, json, boolean, jsonschema

My request succeeds if either of the two required boolean fields is not present. However, I need the behavior where if one of the required fields is empty or missing or incorrect it gives a custom error.

My schema responds with an error if I change the type of the parameters "**own**" and "**closed**" to strings or enums, which is exactly what I want, but the types of the parameters in my request should remain booleans not strings or enums.

My JSON schema:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "someSchema",
  "type": "object",
  "description": "template",
  "properties": {
    "own": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": false
    },
    "space": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "card": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "closed": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
    "required": [
      "id",
      "closed",
      "own",
      "type"
  ]
}
```

For some reason this request succeeds, but must be rejected because a required "**own**" field is missing:

```json
{
  "space": "test",
  "card": "test",
  "closed": false,
  "id": "11_223_334"
}
```

It's the same for when the required "**closed**" field is missing:

```json
{
  "space": "test",
  "card": "test",
  "own": true,
  "id": "11_223_334"
}
```

And for when I replace "**own**" or "**closed**" types with strings instead of booleans:

```json
{
  "space": "test",
  "card": "test",
  "own": "blablabla",
  "id": "11_223_334"
}
```

So, if any of the required parameters that are string types are missing, then it works exactly the way I want it to, which is to give me an error, but for some reason, it doesn't work with boolean types and my request goes through.

Why does JSON Schema work that way? Are there any mistakes I am making and how can I make it better so that the schema behaves the way I would like it to?

Comment: This is not correct JSON Schema behavior. The library you are using to validate this schema has a bug.

Comment: @Jason Desrosiers you're right and i thought about it, but wasn't sure. I use jackson-databind-2.11.3, but can't find information about the bug yet